# Samsung S3 colors issue

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

We are experiencing a color change only in S3.

The color is well defined as Hex in the layout XML.

on all devices it is green, but on S3 it some times turns red

Edit due to the negative responses:

Just to be clear, the color was changing on S3 only sometimes, and in run time.

apparently calling set background to a previusly set view caused this to other views in other activities that had the original color set for them as well

Comment: not related to programming

Comment: This question related to programming..he ask background color issue in android programming

Comment: Are you sure the S3 doesn't have "show overdraw" developer option turned on? It changes view's color like this: http://img.blog.csdn.net/20150413180627356

Comment: @wasyl I am sure my view not overdraw..my device samsung GT-P3100..please see my problem in bounty comments.

Comment: @RanjithKumar could you give us what Hex are you using?

Comment: @nayoso I just define color code(ex: #003434) in colors.xml & set this color background in button.. all devices are working correctly.but some times I got issue in samsung tablet. please see my comments under bounty details

Comment: @RanjithKumar did you use any transparency in @color/black_60?

Comment: @nayoso No I don`t use transparency. I just define color code #434343 in colors.xml..But samsung some times refer the another color(ex @color/orange) from colors.xml

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the color in a different way:

```
YourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
```

And so not from the xml-files.

Comment: can you explain why not from xml-files?

Answer (score 1):

dude, I think its not related with your coding or Hex value, check display settings for S3. Go to settings and then select display and then select screen mode and finally choose Natural option from it. Hope it works. You may try other variations from it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently On S3 (at least) if you set in the layout a views background, and then change it programmatically to a different color, the original color will show as the new color throughout your app.

Jitesh Dalsaniya & Salman Khan, you can try and recreate what i have described.

Hope this post will help anyone that runs into this weird issue.